# Floating form elements

Tags: html, css, forms

Essentially I'm trying to float, most of the list item elements horizontally with with the input underneath the label. Here is a template of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

I've included some of the code here:

```
<div>
 <label for="headline">Headline: </label>
 <input type="text" name="headline" value="Milestone" maxlength="50"size="55">
<br>

<div class="dates clearfix">
 <label for="effect_date">Date of Effect:</label>
 <input type="text" name="effect_date">

 <label for="end_date">End Date (opt):</label>
 <input type="text" name="end_date">

 <label>Date Visible:</label>

 <input type="radio" name="is_date_visible" value="2012">

 <label for="is_date_visible_yes">Yes</label>
 <input type="radio" name="is_date_visible">
 <label for="is_date_visible_no">No</label>
 <br>

 <label>Administrative:</label>
 <input type="radio" name="is_adminis" value="1">
 <label for="is_admin_yes">Yes</label>
 <input type="radio" name="is_adminis">
 <label for="is_admin_no">No</label>
</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And the CSS:

```
    .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
    .clearfix:after { clear: both; }
    .clearfix { *zoom: 1; }

    div.dates {

    }
    .dates label {
         display: block;
         color: #2c93d5;
         font-size: 15px;
         margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .dates input {
         display: block;
    }
    ​.dates label, .dates input {
         float: left;

    }
```

I've tried various things with the CSS all to no avail. Essentially I can't get the inputs to drop below the labels and I can't line them all up they usually come out staggered from the top.

I also have a fiddle link I've been working on:

http://jsfiddle.net/vjDEq/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something similar, without using floats:

http://jsfiddle.net/vjDEq/19/

### HTML

```
<div>
    <label for="headline">Headline: </label>
    <input type="text" id="headline" name="headline" value="Milestone" maxlength="50"size="55">
</div>

<div class="dates">
    <label for="effect_date">Date of Effect:
        <input type="text" name="effect_date">
    </label>

    <label for="end_date">End Date (opt):
        <input type="text" name="end_date">
    </label>

    <fieldset>
    <legend>Date Visible:</legend>
        <label for="is_date_visible_yes">
            <input type="radio" name="is_date_visible" id="is_date_visible_yes" value="yes">
            Yes
        </label>

        <label for="is_date_visible_no">
            <input type="radio" name="is_date_visible" id="is_date_visible_no" value="no">
            No
        </label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
    <legend>Administrative:</legend>
        <label for="is_admin_yes">
            <input type="radio" name="is_adminis" id="is_admin_yes" value="1">
            Yes
        </label>

        <label for="is_admin_no">
            <input type="radio" name="is_adminis" id="is_admin_no" value="0">
            No
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
​
```

### CSS

```css
#headline {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

label {display: block;}

.dates label {
    color: #2c93d5;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.dates input {
    display: block;
}

.dates fieldset input {
    display: inline;
}

.dates label, .dates fieldset {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2em;
}

.dates fieldset label {
    margin-right: 1em;        
}
```

Instead of floats, the labels wrap the inputs and are set to inline-block. The radio buttons should be in a fieldset. Note that jsfiddle is adding normalize.css, which removes borders/margins/padding from the fieldset and legend. You have the option of floating the Administrative fieldset to the right if your layout demands it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I figured it out another way by using a lot of divs and it's not possible for me to go back and change it but I'm definitely using your way next time as it's much more elegant.